# Highcharts Legends issue in IE

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, highcharts

I have a `highchart` `stacked column` containing Fruits in the X-axis as `categories` and Total count in the Y-axis as `series`,

```
xAxis: { categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'] }
yAxis: { title: { text: 'Total Count'} }
series: [{name: 'John&Chandler&Steve&Edward',
                 data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]}, 
         {name: 'Jeni&Joseph&Isabella&Dany',
                 data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]}, 
         {name: 'Ethan&Susan&Charlie&Carol',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]}]
```

This is working fine in `Mozilla` and `Chrome`, but in case of `IE` the series content is getting trimmed. Say in `mozilla` it is printing as `John&Chandler&Steve&Edward` but in IE it is printing as `John&Chandler&Steve`.  I am also aware that '&' between the content of chart `series` is the major cause of the issue in `IE`. This is where I refered for
[highcharts.](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked)

Comment: Can you use another character in the series names? How are you generating the series names?

Comment: @Anagio I tried replacing '&' with different characters (+, -, _) it is working fine. But I want to use '&' only. I generated the series in my managed bean, just for test purpose I hard coded the same.

Comment: have you viewed the source or inspected the Legend in IE to check if the entire series name is there? Maybe it's a CSS issue?

Comment: I just tested this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/peter/2sZBm/ in IE9 and it works fine. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I did it, but not able to find out the Legend element

Comment: @Anagio even I checked it in IE9

Comment: @Anagio the Fiddle is just a simulator, and even I tried the same. But the thing is when I run the application in IE i am facing that particular issue

Comment: Do you use any compability mode? I opened also Anagio example and works well in the IE9. so how can we reproduce this issue?